# a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected in Oracle database using python

Tags: oracle, python-2.6

I have a python script what should do is take .csv file and upload it to a table.

I been getting an error saying  `" (lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3] , lines[4], lines[5],lines[6]))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

if someone can help with it it would be  appreciated

```
#!/bin/env python2

import cx_Oracle
import csv
import datetime
import os

hostname = os.environ['Home_Server_DB_SERVER']
port = os.environ['Home_Server_DB_PORT']
service = os.environ['Home_Server_DB_SERVICE']
uname = os.environ['Home_server_DB_ID']
pwd = os.environ['Home_server_DB_PW']
jdbc_url = 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@' + hostname + ':' + port + '/' + service
con = cx_Oracle.connect(uname, pwd, hostname + ': ' + port + '/' + service)
cursor = con.cursor()
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        cursor.execute( "insert into Man_Men_For2 ( date,first_name,last,class,address,phone,email) values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)" , 
        (lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3] , lines[4] , lines[5], lines[6]))  


cursor.close()
con.commit()
con.close()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it?  Try removing the loop and use values that are set in Python instead of read from a file.  I'd also strongly recommend looking at using executemany() for performance, see https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html You can see a dramatic performance difference between execute() and executemany() in the graph in https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/155356052830600180DE/PF/DEV4625-Scalability-and-High-Availability-for-Oracle-Database-Python-Applications_1568931704636001Qx1H.pdf

Comment: @ChristopherJones iin my case i don't think that i need to change the loop because i need to upload the whole .csv file into the table. the method works just fine if you test the code. the main problem that is i am not familiar with the syntax to insert the data to the table using the loop

Comment: https://blog.hartleybrody.com/debugging-code-beginner/